# find non common elements in two list of lists

Tags: python, list, subset, sublist

I have two lists of lists like:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[1,5],[7],[8,9,10],[11]]
B = [[11,2,2],[9,11],[6,14], [17]]
```

and I would like to only extract sublists which don't have any element in common with the other list of lists, so in my case the result would be:

```
res = [[1,5],[7],[6,14],[17]
```

I would also like to extend the formula to more than 2 list of lists, if possible. I cannot find an easy way to do it, so that if I added another list of lists as in the example:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[1,5],[7],[8,9,10],[11]]
B = [[11,2,2],[9,11],[6,14], [17]]
C = [[17,18,19], [14,10],[100,101]]
```

than the result is:

```
res = [[1,5],[7],[100,101]]
```

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know if it is better to tackle the problem using set or with for cycles. So I am stacked right now. I just need an input

Comment: Does the order of elements within each sublist matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't, in principle, but I would like to have a solution that allows me to directly address every subset in the result to the original set it came from. But the main point is to get them, no matter what the order in principle.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you want to be able to tell that the `[1, 5]` in the final result came from `A`?

Comment: yes, that would be the best, but I can also accept a soluton without that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[1,5],[7],[8,9,10],[11]]
B = [[11,2,2],[9,11],[6,14], [17]]
C = [[17,18,19], [14,10],[100,101]]
lst=[A,B,C]
def non_common(ls):
    temp=[]
    for l in ls:
        without_l=[j for j in ls if j!=l] #get the list without the list-element we are iterating
        no_cmn=[i for i in l if (all(set(i).isdisjoint(set(j)) for k in without_l for j in k))]
        temp.extend(no_cmn)
    return temp
result=non_common(lst)
print(result)
```

You can also backtrack every list element to it's list by using enumerate(ls) in the loop.

Comment: where exactly can I use enumerate(ls)?

Comment: That's one approach:
def non_common(ls):
    temp=[]
    indxs=[]
    for m,l in enumerate(ls):
        without_l=[j for j in ls if j!=l] #get the list without the list-element we are iterating
        no_cmn=[i for i in l if (all(set(i).isdisjoint(set(j)) for k in without_l for j in k))]
        indx=[(m,ind) for ind,i in enumerate(l) if (all(set(i).isdisjoint(set(j)) for k in without_l for j in k))]
        temp.extend(no_cmn)
        if indx:indxs.extend(indx) 
    return temp,indxs

Answer (score 2):

We could check the intersection between the union of sublists in `B` and each sublist in `A` (do the same job for each sublist in `B` and the union of sublists in `A`), then concatenate the resulting lists:

```
res = ([s_lst for s_lst in A if not set(s_lst).intersection(set().union(*B))] 
       + [s_lst for s_lst in B if not set(s_lst).intersection(set().union(*A))])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5], [7], [6, 14], [17]]
```

For the more general case, one option is to create a dictionary and use the same idea as above in a loop:

```
lsts = [A,B,C]
d_unions = dict(enumerate([set().union(*X) for X in lsts]))
d_lsts = dict(enumerate(lsts))

out = []
for i, li in d_lsts.items():
    current_union = set.union(*[v for k,v in d_unions.items() if k!=i])
    out.extend([s_lst for s_lst in li if not set(s_lst).intersection(current_union)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5], [7], [100, 101]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function to do the job, then use reduce to apply the results to multiple lists.

```
from functools import reduce
from typing import List


def _find_not_common(list_a: List[List], list_b: List[List]):
    """"Returns sub lists in A that have no elements in present B"""
    flat_b = set([i for sub_list in list_b for i in sub_list])
    return [
        sub_list
        for sub_list
        in list_a
        if all([j not in flat_b for j in sub_list if j])
    ]


def find_not_common(list_a: List[List], list_b: List[List]):
    """"Returns sub lists in A that have no elements present in B + the viceversa"""
    return _find_not_common(list_a, list_b) + _find_not_common(list_b, list_a)


A = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5], [7], [8, 9, 10], [11]]
B = [[11, 2, 2], [9, 11], [6, 14], [17]]
C = [[17, 18, 19], [14, 10], [100, 101]]

# Use reduce to pass a list of any length.
result = reduce(find_not_common, [A, B, C])  # Output: [[1, 5], [7], [100, 101]]
```